# How to change the value of an element using EventListener

Tags: javascript, html

In this program, I'm able to add inputs with a button but I need to show the length of each input as it changes. I'm able to get the length using an EventListener, but I'm not sure how to change the text value for any newly created buttons.

On line 12, you can see that I'm able to change the value successfully on the first input but I'm using an html variable. If you look at my addCell() function, you'll see that I have an element as a child of each node to keep track of the length of each input. I need to access that element in my change() function so I can set the event.target.value.length to the corresponding nodes child element.

I've tried using this, setting var x = this and I've tried using the event.target properties to find the corresponding node and even innerHTML.

```js
var i = 0;
var count = 1;
var length = 2;
var chars = 0;

document.addEventListener('input', function (evt) {
  change(evt);
});

function change(elem) {
  var check = document.getElementById("first");
  if (event.target == check) {
    document.getElementById("len").innerHTML = event.target.value.length;
    return;
  }

  // Here's where I'm stuck

}

function removeCell() {
  if (count <= 1) {
    alert("Illegal operation, the police have been notified.")
    return;
  }
  var elem = document.getElementById('main');
  elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
  count = count - 1;
  length = length - 1;
}

function addCell() {
  var node = document.createElement('div');
  node.innerHTML += length;
  var inp = document.createElement('INPUT');
  var size = document.createElement('size');

  inp.setAttribute("type", "text");
  node.appendChild(inp);
  node.appendChild(size);
  document.getElementById('main').appendChild(node);

  count += 1;
  length += 1;
  i += 1;
}
```

```css
#area {
  width: 585px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto
}
#texts {
  width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
}
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  <form id="main">
    <pre><b>          input </b>          length</pre>
    <span id="list">
      1<input type="text" id="first"> <var id="len"></var>
    </span>

  </form>
  <br />
  <button onclick="addCell()">Add Cell</button>
  <button onclick="removeCell()">Remove Cell</button>
  <button onclick="sort()">Sort</button>
</div>
```

Since I'm able to use alert() to show me the correct length of each newly created input each time it changes, I know there's a way to access the "size" element I created to update it using event.target.value.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you use a "global" input event listener and your `change()` function is not programmed to handle multiple input fields because in it you are querying known element ids `first` and `len`.

If you want to go with a global listener you have to tell your `change()` function how to access the new input and corresponding target fields.

An easier way is that you modify your `addCell()` function and attach an event listener to the input field that you are creating instead of using a global one. Thereby each input field holds its own event listener. Since both the input field and your size element, which displays the length of the input value, are created in the same scope you can use easily write the length to the corresponding size element.

```
inp.addEventListener('input', function(){
  size.innerText = inp.value.length;
});
```

If you want this to work with your provided HTML you need to remove your first input field and call `addCell()` manually so that your initial input gets rendered.

Your code should then look like this (**note:** I set `var count = 0;` and `var length = 1;`):

```js
var i = 0;
var count = 0;
var length = 1;
var chars = 0;

function removeCell() {
  if (count <= 1) {
    alert("Illegal operation, the police have been notified.")
    return;
  }
  var elem = document.getElementById('main');
  elem.removeChild(elem.lastChild);
  count = count - 1;
  length = length - 1;
}

function addCell() {
  var node = document.createElement('div');
  node.innerHTML += length;
  var inp = document.createElement('INPUT');
  var size = document.createElement('size');

  inp.setAttribute("type", "text");
  inp.addEventListener('input', function(){
    size.innerText = inp.value.length;
  });
  node.appendChild(inp);
  node.appendChild(size);
  document.getElementById('main').appendChild(node);

  count += 1;
  length += 1;
  i += 1;
}

addCell();
```

```css
#area {
  width: 585px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto
}
#texts {
  width: 220px;
  height: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
}
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="area">
  <form id="main">
    <pre><b>          input </b>          length</pre>
    <span id="list"></span>
  </form>
  <br />
  <button onclick="addCell()">Add Cell</button>
  <button onclick="removeCell()">Remove Cell</button>
  <button onclick="sort()">Sort</button>
</div>
```

Comment: I had a feeling my setup was a bit off, the way you set up the addCell() function makes much more sense. Adding the event listener directly to the input on node creation looks very elegant and saves a lot of trouble. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- If HTML layout is planned out and is consistent you can use `[name]` attribute for form controls and `.class` or even just the `tagName`. Use of `#id` when dealing with multiple tags is difficult and unnecessary. Just in case if you weren't aware of this critical rule: ***`#ids` must be unique there cannot be any duplicate `#ids` on the same page. Having duplicate `#ids` will break JavaScript/jQuery 90% of the time.***
- To accessing tags by `.class`, `#id`, `[name]`, `tagName`, etc. use [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) for multiple tags.
- To access forms and form controls (input, output, select, etc) by `[name]` or `#id` use the [**HTMLFormElement** and **HTMLFormControlsCollection** APIs](https://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/forms/).
- `.innerHTML` is destructive as it overwrites everything within a tag. [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) is non-destructive and can place an htmlString in 4 different positions in or around a tag.
- Event handlers and event listeners work only on tags that were initially on the page as it was loaded. Any tags dynamically added afterwards cannot be registered to listen/handle events. You must delegate events by registering an ancestor tag that's been on the page since it was loaded. This was done with `delRow()` since the buttons are dynamically created on each row (changed it because one delete button that removes the last row isn't that useful. ex. 7 rows and you need to delete 4 rows just to get to the third row).
- Here's a breakdown of: `[...ui.len]` `ui` references all form controls `.len` is all tags with the `[name=len]`. The brackets and [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) converts the collection of len tags to an array.
- There's no such thing as `<size></size>`. So `document.createElement('size')` is very wrong.

```js
const main = document.forms.main;

main.oninput = count;
main.elements.add.onclick = addRow;
document.querySelector('tbody').onclick = delRow;

function count(e) {
  const active = e.target;
  const ui = e.currentTarget.elements;
  const row = active.closest('tr');
  const idx = [...row.parentElement.children].indexOf(row);
  const length = [...ui.len][idx];
  length.value = active.value.length;
  return false;
}

function addRow(e) {
  const tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
  let last = tbody.childElementCount+1;
  tbody.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<tr><td data-idx='${last}'><input name='txt' type="text"></td><td><output name='len'>0</output></td><td><button class='del' type='button'>Delete</button></td>`);
  return false;
}

function delRow(e) {
  if (e.target.matches('.del')) {
    const row = e.target.closest('tr');
    let rows = [...row.parentElement.children];
    let qty = rows.length;
    let idx = rows.indexOf(row);
    for (let i = idx; i < qty; i++) {
      rows[i].querySelector('td').dataset.idx = i;
    }
    row.remove();
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

#main {
  width: 585px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
  color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  min-height: 100px;
  height: auto
}

tbody tr td:first-of-type::before {
  content: attr(data-idx)' ';
}
```

```html
<form id="main">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class='txt'>input</th>
        <th class='len'>length</th>
        <th><button id='add' type='button'>Add</button></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td data-idx='1'><input name='txt' type="text"></td>
        <td><output name='len'>0</output></td>
        <td><button class='del' type='button'>Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <!--These are dummy nodes because of the
  HTMLFormControlsCollection API ability to use id or name, there
  must be at least 2 tags with the same name in order for it to
  be considered iterable-->
  <input name='txt' type='hidden'>
  <input name='len' type='hidden'>
</form>
```